# Phaser Typescript Ionic 2 Error

Tags: typescript, npm, ionic2, phaser-framework

I am trying to work on an Ionic 2 application with some phaser functionally. I start off by doing a simple

```
ionic start
```

Once that finished i do

```
npm install phaser --save
```

Once phaser is installed i went to the templates about.ts pages and put in this line of code

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';
```

Then I am simply just trying to do this to make sure everything is working

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  console.log(Phaser)
}
```

No matter what I am always getting errors. [image: Image of error Lod]

Those error above are generally what I am getting but something when I try to change files I get this error

[image: PIXI missing]

I do not know what else to try. I have been searching all over trying to find a solution and I cannot find anything. I have tried editing the files that ionic says the errors are coming from with no luck. I have also tried using the phaser-ce edition with no luck there either. If anyone has any ideas for how i can get this working that would be so helpful thank you!

Comment: have you installed typings?

Comment: I just tried that again. I did two methods 'typings install --global phaser' and 'npm install --save @types/phaser' neither of which worked. It could not find the typings so I'm not sure if I'm doing that wrong or if they don't exist online. I found this page: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/2746 where they address pretty much the issues I'm having but when I make the change to the package.json i get the error i show above about PIXI is not defined.